# Decimal.js how to get integer and fraction part separate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, decimal.js

I am using decimal.js light in my angular application.

I want to get integer and fraction part by using Decimal.js.

Eg. input: 123.45
integer: 123
decimal: 45

Comment: Anyway you can expand what you mean by "I want to get integer and fraction part"? Possibly include some code with what you have tried and output you are receiving would be helpful.

Comment: for nonnegative numbers, Decimal.trunc(x) should give the integer part and x-Decimal.trunc(x) should give the fractional part

Comment: @JeremyKahan `Decimal.trunc` works for integer part. Can't find function `x-Decimal.trunc`

Comment: Dumb question, but why aren't you using a `String.split('.')` function?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Isn't that dumb when the number is exponential.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put spacing. What I'm suggesting for the fractional part is to subtract, thus x - Decimal.trunc(x). Again, I'm assuming positive, so probably work on the absolute value and then use the sign property of the original x on the resulting parts.

Comment: But to get precision for the frac part use x.minus(Decimal.trunc(x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the integer part use the trunc function built into Decimal.
For the fractional part, subtract off the whole part with the minus function built in to Decimal (otherwise you lose the precision of Decimal, which was what you wanted to have). Decimal appears to handle negative numbers without additional code.

Here is an example. You can mess with the original number to test various cases.

```
var x = new Decimal(-123.4533e2);
var msg = 'Original number '+x;
console.log(msg);
msg = 'Whole part is '+Decimal.trunc(x);
console.log(msg);
msg = 'Frac part is '+x.minus(Decimal.trunc(x));
console.log(msg);
```

or in the above you can replace `Decimal.trunc(x)` with `x.trunc()`